# VMWare Failed to start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vmware, vmware-player, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

**This is Error output from "systemctl status vmware" command :**

```
● vmware.service - LSB: This service starts and stops VMware services
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vmware; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-03-31 15:35:54 WITA; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12791 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vmware start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vmware.service
           ├─11081 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmblock-fuse -o subtype=vmware-vmblock,default_permissions,allow_other /var/run/vmblock-fuse
           └─11105 /usr/sbin/vmware-authdlauncher

Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: Starting VMware services:
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [37B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [52B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [53B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [33B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [30B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> vmware[12791]: [41B blob data]
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> systemd[1]: vmware.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> systemd[1]: vmware.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 31 15:35:54 <username> systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: This service starts and stops VMware services.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Reboot and make sure you choose the latest kernel in your grub menu (should be the default)

```
sudo reboot
```

Re-install the VMware Workstation Kernel modules

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Reboot one more time to make sure the modules load

```
sudo reboot
```

[This](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Failed-to-start-LSB-This-service-starts-and-stops-VMware/td-p/449973) worked for me.

Comment: @Ullman, Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same with my `Ubuntu-20.04-LTS` now.